# How to get a value in a tuple in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to access the values in a tuple within a dictionary using a lambda function

I need to get average GPA for each subject by comparing the average grades of the students in that class

I have tried using a lambda but I could not figure it out.

```py
grade = {'A': 4.0, 'B': 3.0, 'C': 2.0, 'D': 1.0, 'F' : 0.0}

subjects = {'math': {('Jack', 'A'),('Larry', 'C')}, 'English': {('Kevin', 'C'),('Tom','B')}}


def highestAverageOfSubjects(subjects):
    return
```

The output needs to be `['math','English']` since average GPA of math which is 3.0 is greater then English 2.0 average GPA

Comment: Is the question "How to access a value in a tuple?" or "How to calculate avg GPA?"

Comment: sorry it should compare average GPA each subject so output needs to be ['math','English']. because average GPA of math which is 3.0 is greater then English 2.0 average GPA

Comment: You didn't answer my question. What exactly are you asking here? How to access elements of a tuple or how to find avg gpa?

Comment: how to find avg gpa..then I think I will be able to know how to access elements of a tuple

Comment: Take a look at my updated answer in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily sort everything by using `sorted` with a `key` function:

```
Grade = {'A': 4.0, 'B': 3.0, 'C': 2.0, 'D': 1.0, 'F' : 0.0}
subject = {'math': {('Jack', 'A'),('Larry', 'C')}, 'English': {('Kevin', 'C'),('Tom','B')}}
result = sorted(subject, key=lambda x: sum(Grade[g] for _, g in subject[x]) / len(subject[x]), reverse=True)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
['math','English']
```

If, as a secondary, you want to sort by the number of students:

```
result = sorted(subject, key=lambda x: (sum(Grade[g] for _, g in subject[x]) / len(subject[x]), len(subject[x])), reverse=True)
print(result)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Do you know how to sort by students number if GPA is same.

Comment: @KevinLee What do you mean by "students number"? Do you mean the number of students?

Comment: @KevinLee I made an edit assuming that's what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

One of the issues with the way you have implemented is that you have used a `set` as values in your `subject` dict. This means you have to range over each element. But once you have the element, that value would simply be indexed like `elem[1]`.

For ex:

```
Grade = {'A': 4.0, 'B': 3.0, 'C': 2.0, 'D': 1.0, 'F' : 0.0}
subject = {'math': {('Jack', 'A'),('Larry', 'C')}, 'English': {('Kevin', 'C'),('Tom','B')}}
for elem in subject['math']:
    print(elem[1])
```

Output:

```
C
A
```

If in the `print` above you just `print(elem)` then you'd see something like:

```
('Larry', 'C')
('Jack', 'A')
```

So this way you could easily extend your `highAveSub(subject)` implementation to get what you want.

To find the avg grade of a subject:

```
def highAveSub(subname):
    total = 0
    for elem in subject[subname]:   #Because your values are of type set, not dict.
        total = total + grade[elem[1]]    #This is how you will cross-reference the numerical value of the grade. You could also simply use enums and I'll leave that to you to find out
    avg = total / len(subject[subname])
    return avg
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation in the function; it's kind of unclear what exactly you're trying to accomplish right now.

Comment: Fixed the indentation. I was trying to not write down the whole solution but let the OP figure out the missing bits. From their follow-up comments it seemed that calculation of avg using values in tuples was an issue. So addressed just that.